# angular typeahead filter error "undefined is not a function"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I have a working plunkr here: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ekDQRs?p=preview), which defines and uses a filter that appends an item to the typeahead list of suggestions. When I try to incorporate into my project, it throws an error around the filter. Here's my code:

html:

```
<div class="input-group" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
            <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search for vendors or products" class="form-control"
               ng-bind-html="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"
              typeahead="product for product in getProductSuggestions($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue | finalAppend:$viewValue">
```

script:

```
var app = angular.module('clientApp')
app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function ($scope, $http, StateService) {
    $scope.getProductSuggestions = function(val) {
        return $http.get(StateService.getServerAddress() + "search/autocomplete?q=" + val
            ).then(function(response){
            return response.data.products;
        });
    };
  })

app.filter('finalAppend', function($sce){
      return function(array, value){
        array.push(  // error: undefined is not a function!
            $sce.trustAsHtml('Look for <b>' + value + '</b> in other shops')
        ); 
        return array;
      }
})
```

thanks in advance.

EDIT: In the end I just got rid of the filter and I'm appending the last thing in the promise itself when I get the results back.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function `getProductSuggestions` is not retrieving an Array. That's because that function is making an asinc request and you have the `return` set in the function of the `then` promise.

You need to change your code quite a bit.

In your view do this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search for vendors or products" 
  class="form-control" 
  ng-change="updateProductSuggestions(search)" 
  ng-bind-html="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"
  typeahead="product for product in productSuggestions | filter:$viewValue | finalAppend:$viewValue">
```

And in your controller do this:

```
app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function ($scope, $http, StateService, $timeout) {
    $scope.productSuggestions =[];
    $scope.updateProductSuggestions= function(val) {
        return $http.get(StateService.getServerAddress() + "search/autocomplete?q=" + val
            ).then(function(response){
            $timeout(function(){
                  $scope.productSuggestions = response.data.products;
            });
        });
    };
  })
```

Also, make sure that what you are getting in `response.data.products` is a valid Array.

And finally, you could also improve your `$filter` like this:

```
app.filter('finalAppend', function($sce){
      return function(array, value){
        if(!(array && value))
            return array;
        array.push(
            $sce.trustAsHtml('Look for <b>' + value + '</b> in other shops')
        ); 
        return array;
      }
})
```

Comment: mmm I don't understand how that if not array and value would help to get this working? to me seems like if will throw an error anyways, but could you elaborate more on why it shouldn't?

Comment: @Josep, ng-change="updateProductSuggestions($viewValue)" passes undefined value for val. Also I don't understand how come the promise approach works when I don't use the filter.

Comment: @Riz ups! Give me a sec, let me fix that

Comment: @Riz it should be `ng-change="updateProductSuggestions(search)"`

Comment: @rahpuser that `if` statement is not there in order to fix the issue, but to ensure that if the custom `$filter` is not used with the correct parameters no exception will be raised. Without that `if` statement if the filter is used with an undefined `Array`, the $filter will throw an error, also if the value of `value` is `undefined` there is no point on appending that last line, therefore the original `Array` should be retrieved.

Comment: hi @Josep thanks for the response. It works, but the typeahead results are always one character behind because the promise is async and doesn't always return before typeahead summons the productSuggestions array.

Comment: @Riz right! you need to use `$apply`, let me update the answer.

Comment: @Riz I just updated the answer, please try it out and let me know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Josep it gives me :Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Comment: @Riz I just updated my answer, try using `$timeout` instead (notice that you will have to add the dependency in the declaration of you controller)

Comment: @Josep thanks for your help, but it still was behind in refreshing. In the end I just got rid of the filter and I'm appending the last thing in the promise itself when I get the results back.