# angular-filter groupby filter returns an "undefined" field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm grouping a large json array. Its working, but at the end of the array, I'm getting an "undefined" category.

```
'The University and Jepson Herbaria
- California Herbs Collection
University of California Museum of Paleontology
- UCMP Vertebrate Collection
undefined
-
-
```

I'm having trouble figuring our where this is coming from. Here's the code I'm using.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in datasources | groupBy: 'institution'" > {{ key }}
    <li ng-repeat="collection in value">
        {{ collection.name }}
    </li>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

I think it might be a remix of the problem this guys was having, but I'm not quite following the problem -- I'm new to angular and js: [angular typeahead filter error "undefined is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721281/angular-typeahead-filter-error-undefined-is-not-a-function)

UPDATE:
When I change collection.name to collections (so I just dump the values of the keys)

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in datasources | groupBy: 'institution'" > {{ key }}
    <li ng-repeat="collection in value">
        {{ collection }}
    </li>
</div>
```

i get:

```
'The University and Jepson Herbaria
- (...long value...)
University of California Museum of Paleontology
- (...long value...)
undefined
- {}
- true
```

Its like its looping through everything but there's 2 extra things. The source for the groupBy function is here: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/blob/master/src/_filter/collection/group-by.js

I'm not competent enough in js to make heads or tails of it though.

Comment: You need to post what is in `datasources` or at least the record that shows that problem

Comment: are there places to dump big (not very big, but not small) json files?

Comment: See http://jsonfiddle.net and/or http://pastebin.com/

Comment: heres the json: http://pastebin.com/X6keLSku

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue with the info you've supplied - http://plnkr.co/edit/BWBJkhjVfMMoWvj6rwSB?p=preview - How/where are you loading the json?

Comment: @james -- I'm loading the data from a service I have. When I check network tab, it shows the json that's in pastebin. That makes me think the service is working. Also when I use ng-repeat="(key,value) in datasources" it works fine -- only when I use groupby I get the extra undefined field. I think you're right to think it might be an issue with how its loaded, but I don't know what the issue could be.

Comment: okay, so at the end of my list I return - key: undefined. I get two objects returned. One is an object containing functions: then, catch, and finally. Another is a boolean -- true. Is there anyway that groupby can append these to a list?

Comment: groupby just iterates over whatever you pass it and uses the second argument - in your case 'institution' - to group the values it finds. It sounds like you're setting `datasources` as the entire service response, not just the data. Can you paste your service code as well please?

Comment: its pretty messy. the part to look at is: .factory('RetrieveDataSources_flat', function($resource)

http://pastebin.com/tzq0xDaA

Comment: i found $$hashkey in one of the objects that was appeneded to datasources. it looks like Angular appends this to check if something is updated. maybe its appending this to the end of the json array?

Comment: where does it get assigned to the `datasources` property? What does that code look like?

Comment: in the controller (line 64):
http://pastebin.com/KkkBfaVU

And I call ng-controller="DisplayDataSourcesCtrl" in the div of the page im working on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67504/discussion-between-james-and-yoshi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @james for your help!! I was stuck all day.

I was using a factory to return a json object. When this is done, some other stuff gets tacked on.
[Why does angular $resource add extra objects ($promise, $resolve...) to my data response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548161/why-does-angular-resource-add-extra-objects-promise-resolve-to-my-data)

The point is $promise and $resolved get returned. If you loop on the new object, these come along for the ride.

To strip the variables that Angular adds and only work with your data use: angular.toJson. Then turn it back to a json object with JSON.parse.

```
$scope.datasources = JSON.parse(angular.toJson(data))
```